# No data is read from Realm file

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I want to have some initial data in Realm database file. I followed the instructions on how to create a bundle, put bundle file in `android/app/src/main/assets/bundle.realm` and added attribute `path` with value `bundle.realm`.

Anyway, whatever I filter the result is an empty array so I assume existing Realm file is not found or I am doing something wrong with the queries. I don't event know how to test the former as no error is thrown if the file does not exits.

So, how do I read data from `Realm` file on Android?

Relevant code sections:

`database.ts`

```
import { TimeSeriesData } from './models';
import { Realm, createRealmContext } from '@realm/react';

Realm.copyBundledRealmFiles();

const { RealmProvider, useRealm, useObject, useQuery } = createRealmContext({
  schema: [TimeSeriesData],
  path: 'bundle.realm',
});

export { RealmProvider, useRealm, useObject, useQuery };
```

`App.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Initializer, Routes } from './src/components/common';
import { RealmProvider, useQuery } from './src/database';

const App = () => {
  return (
    // ...
    <RealmProvider>
      <Routes />
    </RealmProvider>
    // ...
  );
};

export default App;
```

`TasksList.tsx`

```
// ...
const timeSeriesData = useQuery(TimeSeriesData);

return (
  <View>
    {timeSeriesData.filtered('indexTime < 100').map(item => (
      <Text> {item.indexTime} </Text>
    ))}
  </View>
);
```

---

##### Update

From `realm.path` I found that Realm file is read from `/data/data/com.<app name>/files/bundle.realm` so I could upload it manually. Anyway, I do not understand why `Realm.copyBundledRealmFiles()` does not copy the file over there.